# YouTube API 2.0 and 3.0 Returning different rresults

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

I'm working on a website that retrieves public videos from a YouTube channel to populate a video list on the site.

The published page is using the 2.0 version of the API with a base request URL of: `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/z8xDwdqXrHVc-8b4ZsA0Sw/uploads?max-results=15`

This URL successfully returns the 6 public videos available on the specified channel.

I'm in the process of migrating to the 3.0 API, and I've noticed a discrepancy in the results returned from the new request:

```
$searchResults =  $youtube -> search -> listSearch( 'snippet', array(
    'channelId' => 'UCz8xDwdqXrHVc-8b4ZsA0Sw',
    'maxResults' => 15,
    'type' => 'video'
) );
```

With this request, I would expect `$searchResults` to contain the same 6 videos as the old 2.0 API request, however, the 3.0 request returns a response with zero results.

I am reasonably certain that I have ruled out an error in my setup of the Google_Service_YouTube and Google_Client objects.

I replaced the `channelId` parameter above with the channel ID of my own personal YouTube channel (UC2qJ2qvc_fRp3xLtWKNPucw), and received a response with the 10 public videos I have on that channel.

What would cause this discrepancy?

## EDIT

Since making this post, I have removed all videos from the channel in question. The videos were originally uploaded using the export feature available through twitch.tv. I downloaded the original files and resubmitted the videos directly through YouTube, and now all 6 videos appear in the API response as expected.

At this point, I've got the feed working and developed a plan for video upload management that should prevent this from resurfacing. However, I'd still like to understand what would cause the inconsistency. Why would videos uploaded to the channel via Twitch be excluded from the search results?

Comment: if i try to your request with 'UCz8xDwdqXrHVc-8b4ZsA0Sw' it's working fine. You can try : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: It only sort of works. I deleted a couple videos and re-uploaded them. Those two videos now appear, but there should be 6. It looks like the issue is tied to videos uploaded via Twitch export. Those videos are not included in the results, but videos uploaded through YouTube are retrieved just fine.

Comment: This is really interesting, and points to something wrong with the underlying data management; it seems likely that it isn't properly indexing videos that come through Twitch; the interesting question would be whether or not it's something that Twitch is doing (a thorough scan of the metadata from a Twitch exported video in comparison to one you've uploaded could help), or whether the problem lies in videos uploaded through the API in general. Do you have another app that can upload directly to YouTube that you could test on? Alternatively, you could file a bug on the issue.

Comment: That is definitely on my todo list. Unfortunately, I don't have another app to compare it to, but I did see similar issues with the v2 API when using the orderby parameter. I never resolved that as the presence of that issue is what led me to upgrade my site to use the v3 API.